# Usage report not working at site level SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-usage, reporting

I'm trying to generate usage reports for our SharePoint 2013. Configured usage reporting in CA. Enabled receivers. 
However, Usage report is not generating at site level..when URL is https://site/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSite (i.e. popularity trends). We are able to generate report at site collection level through popularity and search reports ..url: https://site/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSiteCollection.
Is there some feature or anything that I have to activate?
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Please fine the below details

The Reporting feature in the Site Collection Features needs to be activated. 
[image]

When this feature was activated, the popularity trends populated 0 results

[image]

This was because there was receiver for the usage services. We gave the below code to be able to query the Service with the below code.

```
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"} 
$aud | fl

$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
$prud | fl
```

This returns the below information.
[image]

Notice there is no receiver attached.

The below code will apply the Microsoft extensions.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"} 
# if analytics usage definition receivers is empty then manually add back receiver 
if($aud.Receivers.Count -eq 0) 
{ 
    $aud.Receivers.Add("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.Internal.AnalyticsCustomRequestUsageReceiver") 
} 
# if analytics usage definition receiver is not enabled then enable it 
if($aud.EnableReceivers -eq $false) 
{ 
    $aud.EnableReceivers = $true 
    $aud.Update() 
} 
$aud | fl 
$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}  
# if page requests usage definition receivers is empty then manually add back receiver 
if($prud.Receivers.Count -eq 0) 
{ 
    $prud.Receivers.Add("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.Internal.ViewRequestUsageReceiver")  
} 
# if page requests usage definition receiver is not enabled then enable it
if($prud.EnableReceivers -eq $false) 
{ 
    $prud.EnableReceivers = $true 
    $prud.Update() 
} 
$prud | fl
```

This will apply the receivers. Running the below code we can check the outcome.

```
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"} 
$aud | fl 

$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
$prud | fl
```

[image]

After 24 hours the reports will start to populate information. This is pending on the timer jobs running which out of the box are set to run daily

Reference

http://www.myriadtech.com.au/blog/Ben/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=7

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. If the link breaks sometime in the future, this answer will be useless. Please add details to your answer and use a link as a source or reference.

Comment: This has been done. Enabled Analytics and Page request receivers. We are able to generate report at site collection level but not at site level